# Webpage renders blank in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm here today about having cross-browser problems. My code renders on Chrome and Firefox perfectly, however it renders a blank page on IE.

Whenever I debug in IE, there is an error that is triggered on the jQuery code snippet that says either "$ is undefined" or "Object Expected".

[image]

Setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css"></link>
<script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
```

Here is one of the jQuery snippets that triggers an error:

```
$(function(){
    $("#accordionDemo").accordion({
        header : "h3",
        active: false,
        alwaysOpen:false,
        fillSpace:false,
        collapsible:true,
    });
});
```

The html is fairly simple. I simply use a script in the body like
 `$('#home').append('<div id="accordionDemo"><b>Sample Code</b></div>');`

I have code within the div by the way. I just wrote sample code as a placeholder.

I'm kinda new to jQuery, but I think I am missing something simple. However, I cant really find the problem. Please help me out here. Let me know if I have to include more details in my question. Thank you SO.

**UPDATE** 
Here is the full code. I have changed the variable names, for security. I have also deleted some parts and condensed it, however, the main gist/layout is still there.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" charset ="UTF-8">
        <title>Handshake Protocol</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //reset type=date inputs to text
            $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
                $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
            }); 
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css"></link>
        <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i=0;
            var xmlFinal;
            var accordianHtml="";
            var accordianHtmlStart='<div id="accordionDemo">';
            var accordianHtmlEnd="</div>";

            $(function(){
                $("#accordionDemo").accordion({
                    header : "h3",
                    active: false,
                    alwaysOpen:false,
                    fillSpace:false,
                    collapsible:true
                });
            });

            $(xmld).find('dummymain').each(function(){ //i am getting this xml file off the net, i have hidden the link for security reasons

                accordianHtml += '<h3>'+dummyname+'</h3><div>';
                accordianHtml += "<button data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-role='button'>Start</button>";
                accordianHtml += "<button data-inline='true' data-mini='true' data-role='button'>Stop</button>";
                accordianHtml += "</div>";
            });

            var accordianHtmlFinal = accordianHtmlStart + accordianHtml + accordianHtmlEnd;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <script>
                $('#home').append('<div data-role="header" id="header"> <h1>dummy Dashboard</h1> </div>');
                $('#home').append(accordianHtmlFinal);
                $('#home').append('<input type="button" value="Save" onlick="send2dummyServer()"/>');
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `collapsible:true,` <----- extra comma

Comment: If `$ is undefined` then that means the jQuery library hasn't been loaded when that code executes.  Are you trying to run the JavaScript code before (above) the `script` tags that load the jQuery libraries?

Comment: No, I have the scripts that load jquery in the beginning of my file. All my javascript code is in a separate script after my script imports.

Comment: The extra comma mentioned by @BradM is definitely an error, and will definitely break your code in IE (and only in IE).

Comment: @BradM: yeah my bad simple error, but it still does not change the problem. Thanks for catching it though!

Comment: You need to paste ALL your code in one block. Segments isn't working with this error. We should be able to see whats wrong if we can see the whole picture.

Comment: @chaitanya.varanasi I have created a html page with that source and it's working fine in IE so the problem isn't included in this code.

Comment: I still get Object Expected errors on line 13,27,51,52,53

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#home').append('<div id="accordionDemo"><b>Sample Code</b></div>');
```

Note the quotes.

Comment: Yeah sorry my original code has the quotes correctly. I made a mistake when I was writing it out in the question. I appreciate it though. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your jquery code inside in the document ready event, otherwise you can't guarantee that the JQuery framework has been properly loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#home').append('<div id="accordionDemo"><b>Sample Code</b></div>');
});
```

[See here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for more information.

Comment: I have that code in my HTML <body> tag. Ill try this and let you know!

Comment: You also had a problem with the quotes as @Zhelyo Hristov mentioned. I've edited my answer with the correct syntax for the quotes...

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @BradM, you have an extra comma after `collapsible:true`. While this may be tolerated in some browsers, it is syntactically incorrect and therefore rejected by IE.

Since you have a syntax error, `$` isn't loaded properly and therefore trying to access it is an error.

Comment: Yeah I fixed the extra comma, however the same errors like '$ is undefined' still appear.

Comment: This is *not* syntactically incorrect. It is a bug in IE's interpretation of the standard. I don't have link, but you can look it up.